# python: don't understand "while len(list1) and len(list2):"

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm learning python and working through the google code course. In the list2.py example they ask us to write a function:

> Given two lists sorted in increasing order, create and return a merged
>       list of all the elements in sorted order. You may modify the passed in lists.
>       Ideally, the solution should work in "linear" time, making a single
>       pass of both lists.

And they give the code:

```
def linear_merge(list1, list2):
  result = []
  #Look at the two lists so long as both are non-empty.
  #Take whichever element [0] is smaller.
  while len(list1) and len(list2): 
    if list1[0] < list2[0]:
      result.append(list1.pop(0))
    else:
      result.append(list2.pop(0))

  #Now tack on what's left
  result.extend(list1)
  result.extend(list2)
  return result
```

I just have a question about the while loop. I'm not sure I understand what the Boolean test is and when it fails and breaks the loop. Could anyone help me get a better understanding of this?

Comment: _while len(list1) and len(list2):  this means, if len(list1) and len(list2) are True_, which is len(list1)>0 and len(list2)>0, start the _while_ loop.So if those lists are empty before the _while_ loop, you cant start the loop. Booleans, everything has a boolean value, if its not _0_ or _""_ (empty thing) it means this is _True_. If you take mathematic class in scholl you should learn that, 0=False, 1=True. Which means how computers are working actually. 0=There is no electricy, 1=There is electricy.

Comment: @qqvc: That should be an answer, not a comment. BTW, you have a few spelling mistakes.

Comment: @PM2Ring answered, you can you edit please.

Comment: Plus one for the interesting usage. Was my answer a good explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while len(list1) and len(list2):` this means, if `len(list1)` and `len(list2)` are `True`, in other words `len(list1)>0` *and* `len(list2)>0`, start the `while` loop. So if both of those lists are empty before the while loop, the loop won't be entered.

Python values and containers can be used as Boolean (True or False) values. If the value is some kind of zero, or the container is empty, it's considered to be `False`, otherwise it's `True`.

Examples:

```
>>> a=0
>>> bool(a)
False
>>> a=26
>>> bool(a)
True
>>> a=""
>>> bool(a)
False
>>> a=" " #this has a gap, its not "".Realize that, its different than the last example.
>>> bool(a)
True
>>>
```

Also, in Python the Boolean values of True or False can be used in arithmetic: False has an arithmetic value of zero, True has an arithmetic value of one.

Example:

```
>>> True + True
2
```

Often it can be better in Python to use `while True:` and break out of the loop with an `if` statement exactly where you want. But that's not necessary for this `linear_merge()` function.

Example:

```
while True:
    #codes
    if <SomethingHappensThatYouWantToStopTheLoop>:
        break
```

Comment: "Also its better to use `while True:`, and break the loop with an if statement whenever you want." Erm, no. You shouldn't use a `while True` loop unless your loop is supposed to be infinite or near-infinite (e.g. an event loop). If there's a specific situation where the loop should stop, it should be in the loop condition

Comment: It's not infinite, if we use _break_.

Comment: Exactly. It's not supposed to be infinite, so it shouldn't use an infinite loop construct

Comment: Well I wrote that for he asked booleans :-) otherwise you are right

Comment: @qqvc: I think that looks a bit better. :) BTW, `while False:` is useless!

Comment: Thanks for edit, yes I just wrote it because its a boolean too :-)

Answer (score 1):

read it as

> `while len(list1)!=0 and len(list2)!=0:`

meaning that both lists are non-empty

the above solution is actually wrong, since list1 may have been the empty list that terminated the loop

try this:

```
while len(list1) and len(list2): 
  if list1[0] < list2[0]:
    result.append(list1.pop(0))
  else:
    result.append(list2.pop(0))

#Now tack on BOTH lists. one or both will be empty, so only the non-empty one will be tacked on
result.extend(list1)
result.extend(list2)
```

Comment: Yea I think you saw my post before I edited it, i had taken out the extend(list2) in order to test what was happening but my 14-hour day exhausted brain was not doing too well and I forgot to add it back in to this post!!

Answer (score 1):

So the Boolean just checks to see if the lists have an item in them.

So, for example, say you have:

```
 list1 = []
```

Now, this list has nothing stored. So it's Boolean will be false. You can test this by:

```
print(bool(len(list1)))
```

If it's an empty list, it will print
    False

So what this while loop is requiring is that *both* `list1` and `list2` have items (because of the `and`). If either of them is empty, it exits the loop.

Comment: This is correct but the given code actually uses `len(list1)` (unnecessarily, it seems). Maybe you should change your answer to `bool(len([]))` which is still `False` since `0` is falsey

Comment: Wow. I overlooked that, it seems! Thanks, and it's been edited.

Comment: @Crazysheep: I agree that using `len()` is unnecessary. It'd be more Pythonic to do `while list1 and list2:`. OTOH, `len()` is _very_ efficient on built-in Python types, since it doesn't actually count the object's elements - it's just a lookup of the object's stored length attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more Pythonic to write instead of:

```
while len(list1) and len(list2):
```

This:

```
while list1 and list2:
```

They are both semantically the same - they mean while both lists have contents to continue looping. Both zero and an empty list test `False` in a boolean context, and when a list is empty, it's length is zero. In other languages, that's how you do it, but in Python, you just check for the list's boolean value with `if a_list` or `while a_list`.

Comment: I guess my confusion was that it seems to arbitrarily decide what the len() of the lists should be (in this case not zero). Maybe it's my nascent coding skills, but I never would have thought that `while len(list1) and len(list2)` really means "While the length of list1 and list2 are NOT zero." I would have expected that you need to give the condition where the while loop fails (ie: `while len(list1) != 0...`) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The below statement means:

> while len(list1) and len(list2):

That we are only entering the while loop if `len(list1)` and `len(list2)`.

Now in python, `True` evaluates to `1`, and `False` evaluates to `0`, and vice-versa:

```
>>> int(True)
1
>>> int(False)
0
```

So basically whenever the length of both `list1` and `list2` are not equal to `0`, then we will enter the `while` loop, hence, if `list1` and `list2` contain any value that we may want to remove later (foreshadowing of the `.pop()`), then we will enter.

`.pop()` is a method that removes the value at a certain index, and returns that value:

```
>>> _list = ['I', 'am', 'cool']
>>> result = _list.pop(2) #Should return _list[2], hence 'cool', and also remove it from _list
>>> result
'cool'
>>> _list
['I', 'am']
>>>
```

If the `while` loop did not check if the list had any items in it, you would receive this error:

```
>>> _list = ['I', 'am', 'cool']
>>> _list.pop(0)
'I'
>>> _list.pop(0)
'am'
>>> _list.pop(0)
'cool'
>>> _list.pop(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: pop from empty list
>>>
```

You can also try removing the `while` altogether, and see what happens :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The way numbers are evaluated to booleans is that 0 is false, and every other number is true. I believe this is like C and some other languages. So `while len(list)` is saying "while list's length isn't zero", i.e., "while list is not empty".

Comment: not only number, everything except _0_ and _""_ (empty).

Comment: I gotcha, ok so thats why the last 2 lines are necessary, because one way or another, one list will deplete before the other, and then the if statement fails because you can't compare to a null value. So then at that point it's trivial because the lists are already in ascending order. Sorry, it's been a long day so I'm struggling with some obvious stuff >.<

Comment: @Apc0243 This answer is wrong actually, see my comment.

Comment: @qqvc What's wrong with what I wrote? BTW, in your answer you wrote "i > 0", but the actual logic is "i != 0".

Comment: _and every other number is true_ its not correct excatly,it should be not every _number_ , every _thing_.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the floating point zero (0.0) also evaluates to false, and that this is not the same thing as integer zero. (Though when compared, they are both compared as floating point, so `0 == 0.0`.)

Comment: @qqvc `None` also evaluates to `False`. Saying that's not a thing is a game of semantics, and not a useful one. `t = None; bool(t)` is false.

Comment: _none_ == "" and _0_ .

Comment: An empty list is also false. There are probably lots of other values in Python that evaluate to false. You are playing games with semantics that will only confuse, not enlighten.

Comment: @Apc0243 You're almost right, but the test doesn't fail because of any sort of null comparison. The test fails because one list becomes empty. The test is `len(a) and len(b)`, or `if a and b are not empty`. So of course this logic stops when one or both lists have been emptied.

Comment: @piojo yea definitely, my reference was more to the idea that if you used `or` instead of `and` then the comparison will still be made even if one of the lists is empty, in which case the comparison fails. It was a very long day yesterday, I'm surprised I found the "add comment" button!